# BridgeInner configuration file location

Tags: corda

Should the bridge read the path to its certificates from `bridge.conf`? I think so (as explained in the doc) but when I start it, it looks for certificates in `./certificates/` folder:

```
[ERROR] 16:17:53+0200 [main] internal.BridgeStartup.run - Exception during bridge startup
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/corda/bridge/certificates/truststore.jks
```

Here is the block in `bridge.conf`:

```
bridgeMode = BridgeInner
outboundConfig {
    artemisBrokerAddress = "myNodeServer:myNodeServerPort"
}
bridgeInnerConfig {
   floatAddresses = ["floatServer:floatServerPort"]
   expectedCertificateSubject = "CN=Float Local,O=Local Only,L=Paris,C=FR"
   customSSLConfiguration {
           keyStorePassword = "xxx"
           trustStorePassword = "xxx"
           sslKeystore = "./bridgecerts/bridge.jks"
           trustStoreFile = "./bridgecerts/trust.jks"
           crlCheckSoftFail = true
   }
}
networkParametersPath = network-parameters
```

Below the tree :

myServerName:/opt/corda/bridge $ tree .

```
.
├── bridgecerts
│   ├── bridge.jks
│   └── trust.jks
├── bridge.conf
├── corda-bridgeserver-3.1.jar
├── logs
│   └── node-myServerName.log
└── network-parameters
```

2 directories, 6 files

Something I did wrong here ?
The weird thing is that I don't have this issue with the float on another server, set up the same way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bridge has two connections:

- One to the float, called the tunnel connection
- One to the node, called the Artemis connection

The settings in the `bridgeInnerConfig` block configure the tunnel connection. The exception you're seeing is for missing certificates for the Artemis connection. See the docs [here](http://docs.corda.r3.com/bridge-configuration-file.html):

> In particular the BridgeInner setup needs a `certificates` folder
>   containing the `sslkeystore.jks` and `truststore.jks` copied from the
>   node and a copied `network-parameters` file in the workspace folder.

You need to provide the `certificates` folder and `network-parameters` file as described.

You can also configure the Artemis connection using an `outboundConfig` block, but it is not recommended.

Comment: I used `outboundConfig` block for Artemis configuration (see my edit), as it's described in the CE documentation.
By the way, there is no mention of the two parameters related to Artmemis jks in the doc, except if I missed it :-)

Comment: Right but you didn't override the certificates path there?

Comment: No no, actually I didn't know I needed to have certs for artemis in `./certificates/` so thank you it worked.
To be honest, it's not clear in the documentation that this component has to host `sslkeystore.jks`and `truststore.jks` . A little update to clarify the point could be good.